# I have set up osm for india on my machine using docker ! how can i edit the osm map of india which is in pbf file

Tags: routes, openstreetmap

I want to edit the osm file of india which is `.pbf` format and add some custom text or custom location on the map on my local machine. How can I achieve that?

Is there any way to edit `.pbf` files?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I think you may want to more about what your end goal is. Are you trying to plot some points by location? Also, have a look at https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Beginners_Guide_1.3

Comment: The .pbf format is not meant to be edited at all, it is just a very compact transport format. What docker solution did you actually set up? I assume it is one that imported the .pbf data file into a PostGIS database ... so you would have to change the generated database tables directly. The typical solution for adding some custom data on a small scale would be to use OSM data as a base layer, and to put your own data on top as a separate layer ...

Comment: @HartmutHolzgraefe can u please give some insights how to achieve that

Comment: like i have just started using osm and i am not sure how to do that any supporting blogs or articles 

and i have created the osm docker with the help of https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/using-a-docker-container/

yes this is using postgis

Comment: Can you explain in a bit more detail what you're actually trying to display? If it is just a few extra markers for custom points of interest, then using the Leaflet API and a custom marker layer might be what you are actually looking for. See e.g. https://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/

Comment: no i just want to add the location like every other location with leaflet it does not look like that i want to edit the the postgres data of osm and i am not able to find the relation between the tables

@HartmutHolzgraefe
any suggestions how can i add some nodes to the map that should look like every other location?

Comment: so what kind of location we're talking about? city name? shop icon? if so: what kind of shop?

in general, if you want to add a point of interest, the planet_osm_point table would be where you need to insert it ...

Comment: so i just want to insert some of my friends home location and mark it up in the map and it should look like every other location